# Is it possible to create branch that is tracking non-existing remote

Tags: git, scripting, automation

I'd like to checkout a branch in such way that subsequent `git push` will properly push it to origin under same name.

This is easy when remote branch already exists

```
git checkout -b branch origin/branch
```

However, I'd like to do that even if `origin/branch` is not there yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a local branch

```
git checkout -b branch
```

The remote repository doesn't know anything about your local branch, so you must push it the first time "by hand"

```
git push origin branch
```

Now, if you wants your local repository to let it track your local branch with the remote one

```
git branch --set-upstream branch origin/branch
```

Comment: What I'd like is to avoid the "by hand" push, as I don't want to rework my scripts ;)

Comment: This is just to create to remote counterpart and its only required one single time. After this, set the upstream (the third command) you everything should be fine.

Comment: What I am scripting is single-purpose RC branch...but if it's not possible, this is an answer too -- thanks.

Comment: "Create the remote branch" (using git push) may make this work, but IMO it definitely DOES NOT answer the question. I would like to be able to track a non-existent remote branch (when I initialize a new bare project).

Comment: @rektide What do you want to track, if it doesn't exists? You can only reference objects, that exists. "I want my chair to look like that chair over there"-"But there is no chair over there" :? -- To be fair my answers the OPs question, but not yours, because yours is a different with a pretty simple answer: You can't.

Comment: --set-upstream is deprecated. This should be edited to use --set-upstream-to or --track.

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy way, AFAIK.

This is my current stab at it. This is a bash function that sets up a new local branch such that `git push` from that branch pushes to a new remote branch with the same name.

```
function featurebranch() {
  if [ "$@" != "" ]; then
    git branch "$@" origin/master
    git checkout "$@"
    git config branch."$@".remote origin
    git config branch."$@".merge refs/heads/"$@"
    git config branch."$@".rebase true
  fi
}
```

It has to use `git config`, because using `git push -u` or `git branch --track` or `git branch --set-upstream-to` commands all involve a remote branch that actually exists.

I'd appreciate it if any git gurus checked it over and pointed out any problems. Ta. ;-)

Comment: I like it, or at least the idea of it.  Issues (from a non-git-master): (1) git-status says the upstream is gone and prompts you to reset, (2) I would let user specify the from branch, and I would save it as a stand-alone executable bash script, so that it can be named "git-featurebranch" and I wont need to muck with aliases.  I can follow up once I tested my mods

Comment: Gregory - I posted my mods to this here: https://gist.github.com/nhed/239aa94078b0b533d6f5

Comment: This should be the approved answer :)

Answer (score 1):

## Git 1.7.0+

The first, to create a local branch:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
```

At this point the remote repository doesn't know about the local branch, so we need to push it and set the tracking reference.

```
git push -u origin new-branch
```

## Git < 1.7.0

Create a local branch:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
```

Git before version 1.7.0 needs three commands to push the branch and set the tracking reference.

```
git push origin new-branch
git config branch.new-branch.remote origin
git config branch.new-branch.merge refs/heads/new-branch
```

## With Alias (Git 1.7.0+)

*Bonus:* Create a local branch and push a tracked remote branch in one command with this git alias:

```
git config --global alias.cb $'!sh -c \'git checkout -b "$0" && git push -u origin "$0"\''
```

Then to create a new branch, you can just run:

```
git cb new-branch
```

Comment: One can use the steps detailed in git < 1.7.0 in later versions as well to create a branch with a set up tracking branch without making a network request, which may be what the OP was looking for. Doing a `git push` afterwards will create the remote branch.

Comment: My setup: `cb = "!git checkout -b $1; git config branch.$1.remote origin; git config branch.$1.merge refs/heads/$1 #"`

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested . **git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)**

```
1) git checkout -b localBranchNameThatDoesNotExistInRemote

2) Do your changes , and go a git commit 

3) git push origin localBranchNameThatDoesNotExistInRemote --force
```

N.B. - The brunch you are currently on local , and the remote non-existing branch where you are trying to push , **must have the same name**.